# How can I binding to a List in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Here is my code:

```
@page "/"

<button onclick="AddClick">Add</button>
@{ 
    foreach (string i in StringList)
    { 
        <div>@i</div>
    }    
}
@code{
    public List<String> StringList { get; set; }=new List<string>() {"555","666"};
    public void AddClick()
    {
        StringList.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I click the button, it does work yet.

I think it is because I haven't bound the List yet. Meanwhile, how can I bind the List?

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try add @ before onclick:

```
<button @onclick="AddClick">Add</button>
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. `@onclick="AddClick"` looks for a blazor method called `AddClick`, `onclick="AddClick"` looks for a javascript method called `AddClick`.